# I have a DIR-857 that routes cameras accessible via DynDNS, and I need to change the ISP

Tags: networking, routing, ddns

I work at a small company, I'm new and I didn't installed anything of the following; we have a rack with a 24-port switcher, the DIR-857 that routes 9 D-Link cameras (via virtual servers) and 2 modems from different ISPs, everything is currently working with, say, ISP 1 that gives 30 Mbp/s, but ISP 2 gives 200 Mbp/s symmetrically, and we'd like to just switch to ISP 2, could there be any issue? I'd like to point out, we are paying for a DDNS at DynDNS that uses the IP of ISP 1, this is to view our cameras remotely; the other issue I see is that there are many things connected to the switcher, let's say it goes like this: Modem -> DIR-857 Router -> TP-Link Switcher -> Cameras/Workstations/Other switchers (to reach cameras in difficult places or computers in the second floor)

Another thing I'd like to point out is, ISP 1 default subnet is .0.1 and ISP 2 default subnet is .100.1: any assistance would be really helpful, since we do not have contact with the people that installed anything in the first place, I've tried to just connect the modem of ISP 2 to the router but nothing seemed to work, a co-worker told me they saw a technician just changing "something" in the router and proceeding to just plug the cable, but I'm not too sure about this. Thank you for your time

Comment: Shouldn't be too much of an issue. This is what dynamic DNS is used for, changing ip numbers. Just make sure whatever software is updating the ddns gets a refresh and you should be fine. **Note, some ISPs lock the Mac address of the router in use to the account, so changing the router may require a call to the isp to have them release it**.